# SQL int to string to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have date in integers.

What is the cleanest way to convert integers to datetime?

I used this messy way:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,  cast(source.Day as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(source.Month as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(source.Year as varchar(2)), 3),
```

Comment: Which sql-server version are you using?

Comment: an ever more cleaner and safer thing to do is to store your dates using appropriate datatype it is `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( 2010, 12, 31 ) AS Result;
```

Note, it is only available in 2012+ editions.

Comment: Also note that it might not give the desired result when the year is stored as two digits as the method doesn't add 19 or 20 as prefix but rather takes the year as is, meaning that if the year part is 14, the method will return 0014. At least this is how it behaves on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do that

```
   Declare @date date, 
        @year INT = 2014,
        @Month INT = 10,
        @DateDay INT = 12,
        @parseDate char(20)

select @date = CONVERT(date, 
                CAST( Cast(@Year as char(4))
                         + Cast(@Month as char(2)) +
                          cast(@DateDay as char(2))  AS CHAR(12)), 112)
select @date
```

**Note**: I am not handling *NULL* cases.

Comment: You can use `CONCAT` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) instead `+` and it will handle `NULL` cases for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),yourvalue))
```

Comment: @rene:- I didnt get that. Where is it mentioned in the question? I think OP has tried to get the month, day and year from the source!

Comment: @R.T. It's in the code he already has. He's casting the day, month and year to strings and concatenating them.

Answer (score 1):

Working from R.T.s solution this might work

```
CREATE TABLE DATA(yr int, mth int, dy int);
INSERT INTO DATA
VALUES (2014,10,15);

SELECT
      CONVERT (DATETIME,
                CONVERT(char(4), yr) + 
                CONVERT(char(2), mth) + 
                CONVERT(char(2), dy)
       ) as Result
FROM DATA
```

This is still a bit messy and assumes a 4 digit year integer.

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbf62/2